# What does this log message mean?

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to connect to google-plus using GoogleApiClient.When I am using the sign-in-example. For a week ago all worked, but after installing 5.1, I am getting the following error-message:

```
Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzg
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Android Open Source Tracker, this is a known issue.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=91424

> These are warnings and completely harmless. Regardless, most of them are fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like that update changed a crucial Method without leaving the deprecated one there, but that's really only a very first feeling.

Did you update your physical device, emulator, or build tools?

(And did you update your build-tools + sdk too?)